# Kotlin tail recursive function causing stack overflow

Tags: recursion, kotlin, tail-recursion

I was working on [this easy problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/submissions/) to practice basic Kotlin, and I ran into a stack overflow with the following code on the recursive return line:

```
class Solution {
    fun isPalindrome(s: String): Boolean {
        val cleaned = s.toLowerCase().replace(Regex("[^a-z0-9]"), "")
        tailrec fun isPalindrome(start: Int, end: Int): Boolean {
            if (start >= end) return true
            return cleaned[start] == cleaned[end] && isPalindrome(start+1, end-1)
        }
        return isPalindrome(0, cleaned.length-1)
    }
}
```

My understanding of `tailrec` is that it's [supposed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) to convert my recursive function into an iterative one, which wouldn't be susceptible to this sort of crash. If I didn't implement tail recursion correctly, the compiler is supposed to issue an error.

Can someone explain to me why this crashes on large inputs, just like a standard recursive call would?

Comment: Not sure if short-circuiting counts as a tailcall.

Comment: Ah, and leetcode is suppressing warnings, and writing a tailrec function that isn't tail recursive only generates a warning, not an error.

Comment: I'm still curious were the difference is between the `if(...) ... else tailCall()` example in the docs and the `... && tailCall()` in your example. As far as I can see there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior looks like a [missing optimization](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24151) of tail calls in short circuiting operators, where the fact that the last operand is being evaluated means that the expression result doesn't depend anymore on the previous operands.

Meanwhile you can rewrite your return statement as

```
return if (cleaned[start] != cleaned[end]) false else isPalindrome(start+1, end-1)
```

to get the same result + tail call optimization.